# First selector after a li

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zyKpx/) scenario :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="page_item page-item-5 current_page_item">
        <a href="/help">Help</a>
    </li>

    <li class="page_item page-item-7">
        <a href="/follow">Follow</a>
    </li>
</ul>​

li
{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

a
{
    border:1px solid #000000;
}

ul li + page_item a
{
    border:0;
}
```

and, how you an see, I'd like to remove border only on the first link with class `page_item`, with `ul li + page_item a`, but seems it doesnt works?
    ​

Comment: give a class or an id to your ul then do it like `ul#test > li:first-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the `.` in front of your class selector.

Assuming your first `li` will never have the class and you just want to pick the `li.page_item` that comes after it, you can use this selector:

```
ul li:first-child + li.page_item a
{
    border:0;
}
```

But if you want the first `li.page_item a` to not have the border regardless of where it is, you'll need to go about this [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107)...

```
ul li.page_item a
{
    border:0;
}

a, ul li.page_item ~ li.page_item a
{
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is what I asked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You use this code in css file

```
ul li.page_item a{
  border:0px none;
}
```

Comment: this is the true answer of the question. +1

Comment: @Berker Yüceer: No, it's not.

Comment: use !important in the end of none for example border:0px none !important;

Comment: @BoltClock first child gives first li and if you define `a` at the end such as `ul > li:first-child + li.page_item > a` it is the solution. Just needs to add class there oh now i see..

Comment: whats > in ul > li:first-child ? and whats deffrenet between > and first-child ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the class identifier (a `dot`)

Change the last part of your css:

```
ul li.page_item a
{
    border:none;
}
```

also a tip: use `border:none;` instead of `border:0`

Comment: okay sorry. then why not just give your first list item a class="noborder" and then css: .noborder{border:none;} ?

Comment: No! Check BoltClock♦ answer ;)

Comment: great that you found the answer you were looking for :)